# Why the character in 2d game falling when running the game ?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using unity version 5.3.5f1 64bit on windows 10.

I have a ThirdPersonController and when i'm running the game he is just falling down. Instead i want him to hang on to be in Grounded mode so only when using the keys wsad he will walk around the scene like in point and click game.

[image: Scene]

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make him be grounded controller needs to detect `Collider` below player.

To fix this just create big cube with `BoxCollider` as the ground and place it just below the player.

Answer (score 2):

Your player object contains the Rigidbody component which enables Unity physics on your player. Since your player is floating in the air, the game object will fall until it collides with something because of gravity (or from some custom game logic).

You can turn off gravity in the Rigidbody component in the editor by unchecking 'Use Gravity'. You can also change this value within a script - see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html.

Alternatively, you can add a ground that the player lands on by creating a game object with a collider - see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html.